# In which way do image transformations change camera extrinsics?

Tags: linear-algebra, camera-calibration, camera-pose

Given a pinhole camera model, we have an image and according camera intrinsics `K` and extrinsic parameters `R`.

When we scale the image or crop it, the corresponding camera intrinsics `K` change in ways that can be found in literature.

However, assume we transform or distort the image using a projective projection `Q`. How do the intrinsic parameters `K` of the camera change?

For further reference, `Q` is generated by `K * U * K^-1`, where `U` is a rotation matrix.

The projective transformation is illustrated in the two images below:

[image: Input Image]
[image: Transformed Image]

The transformation used in this example is a slight rotation around the vertical axis.